# What's the purpose of the -interface option in tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump

doing the following command:

```
tcpdump -i eth0:cp5
```

shows exactly the same thing as the default   ...

```
tcpdump
```

what's the purpose of allowing user to specify interfaces?

Answer (score 3):

If your computer has several network interfaces, you can choose which one to monitor.

interfaces can proliferate if you have virtual machines with some types of network support.

It is not unusual for servers to have two or more network interfaces and for them to be connected to different subnets (LAN, DMZ, Admin, ...)

```
[root@azure ~]# tcpdump -D
1.eth0
2.br0
3.virbr0
4.any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces)
5.lo
```